# Access data stored in WFFM Reports programmatically

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore6, web-forms-for-marketers

I have a WFFM Form which accepts data fine, and I can also view the reports that are generated within Sitecore, however is there a way that I can access these reports programmatically in C#, something along the lines of iterating through each of the records? Depending on how they are stored, csv etc. So basically is there a way to do it, and if so how do I access it- be it the data source, or some other method. I have looked at this, but to no avail.

[Modifying WFFM Information Using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12518929/modifying-wffm-information-using-c-sharp/13217368#13217368)

http://r-coding-sitecoreblog.blogspot.co.uk/2011/11/extracting-data-from-sitecore-wffm.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no API abstraction layer to access WFFM stored content. That said, the `WebForms` SQL DB is fairly flat structured with just a few tables, so you could do directly SQL queries into it.

Comment: And what am I querying? Where is that DB stored? How would I even retrieve it? XPath, Fast? Thanks for your help Mark.

Comment: The DB is configured in `App_Config/Include/forms.config` and is a SQL DB hosted with the others (core, master, web) on SQL Server. You should open this forms DB in Management Studio and look at the table structure. Getting data from it would require direct SQL queries.

Comment: @MarkUrsino By default the forms database is SQLLite and sits on the production web server in website/Data in Sitecore 6.

Answer (score 0):

The structure of the tables is quite straight forward, and as mentioned, the connection string is available in \app_Config\forms.config

configuration -> sitecore -> formsDataProvider (type="Sitecore.Forms.Data.DataProviders.WFMDataProvider,Sitecore.Forms.Core")

[image]